# How to call generic template function in a specialization version

Tags: c++

Have a problem about how to call the generic template version in a specialization version.

Here is the sample code. But the "vector::push_back(a)" calls itself recursively.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

namespace std
{
        template<>
        void vector<int>::push_back(const int &a)
        {
                cout << "in push_back: " << a << endl;
                vector::push_back(a);               // Want to call generic version
        }
}

int main()
{
        vector<int> v;
        v.push_back(10);
        v.push_back(1);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can. You could use another way, such as `insert(end(), a);`, but what if that method is also specialized? I suspect it is not a good idea to specialize methods of standard containers even if technically legal(?).

Comment: Depending on your reason for wanting this, you could just write a wrapper around `std::vector`, and intercept any member functions you want that way.

Comment: You are only allowed to specialize entire classes from namespace std (and only for user defined types), not individual functions.

Answer (score 9):

When you create specialization for some template (no difference class of function), you tell to compiler to generate **that one instead of general**. So in fact if you have specialization you have no general version for that specialization and you can't call it, because it **doesn't exists**.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply extract the code into another template function:

> ```
>     template<typename T>
>     void baseF(T t) { ... }
>
>     template<typename T>
>     void F(T t) { baseF<T>(t); }
>
>     template<>
>     void F<int>(int t) { baseF<int>(t); }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to complement, I think it works for template function specification in some situations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    virtual int test() {return 0;}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual int test() {return 1;}
};

template<class T>
void TestOutput(T* a)
{
    cout << a->test() << endl;
}

template<>
void TestOutput(Derived* a)
{
    cout << "something else" << endl;
    TestOutput<Base>(a);
}

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    TestOutput(&d);
}
```

I compiled it with visual studio 2013 and the output is:

> something else 
>   1

Although I don't think you can always find a TestOutput function of Base to call the generic one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a modern compiler, you can provide per-type constant expression cases, although it is not so very elegant imho.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class S
{};

template <typename T>
void foo(T & t)
{
    std::cout << "foo generic\n";
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, S>)
    {
        std::cout << "foo specific\n";
    }
}


int main()
{
    auto i = 0;
    foo(i);
    S s;
    foo(s);
}
```